# Error bitmap 0 not defined

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

My code is to check the value returned in some file, i attached the callback to a button , which when pressed should show a dialog box to user based on the return value.
But when code is executed it returns a error message bitmap "0" not defined.

Code :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/wish

##set command "lmstat -a -c /tools/license/dat/cadence_orbit_3x.dat -f Liberate_MX_Client | grep issued | awk {{print $11}}"

set result [exec lmstat -a -c /tools/license/dat/cadence_orbit_3x.dat -f Liberate_LX_Server | grep issued | awk {{print $11}}]
puts $result
if {$result == 0} {
button .hello -text "License Check" -command {checkLic} -bg green 
} else  {
button .hello -text "License Check" -command {checkLic} -bg red 

}
proc checkLic {} {
set val [exec lmstat -a -c /tools/license/dat/cadence_orbit_3x.dat -f Liberate_MX_Client | grep issued | awk {{print $11}}]
puts $val
if {$val == 0} {
after 5000 {destroy .dialog2}
     tk_dialog .dialog2 "Liberate licenses available" info 0 OK

} else  {

after 5000 {destroy .dialog2}
     tk_dialog .dialog2 "No licenses available" info 0 OK
}
}

pack .hello -padx 20 -pady 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [manual page for `tk_dialog`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/dialog.htm) says:

> **tk_dialog** *window title text bitmap default string string ...*
>
> This procedure is part of the Tk script library. It is largely deprecated by the **tk_messageBox**. Its arguments describe a dialog box:
>
> *window:* 
>   Name of top-level window to use for dialog. Any existing window by this name is destroyed.
>
> *title:*
>   Text to appear in the window manager's title bar for the dialog.
>
> *text:*
>   Message to appear in the top portion of the dialog box.
>
> *bitmap:*
>   If non-empty, specifies a bitmap (in a form suitable for **Tk_GetBitmap**) to display in the top portion of the dialog, to the left of the text. If this is an empty string then no bitmap is displayed in the dialog.
>
> *default:*
>   If this is an integer greater than or equal to zero, then it gives the index of the button that is to be the default button for the dialog (0 for the leftmost button, and so on). If less than zero or an empty string then there will not be any default button.
>
> *string:*
>   There will be one button for each of these arguments. Each string specifies text to display in a button, in order from left to right.

I'd guess that you are missing either the *title* or the *text* to use in the dialog, making the value you're intending to supply as *default* fall into the *bitmap* slot, which confuses the code. Add an extra argument, perhaps like this (broken up over two lines just for readability):

```
tk_dialog .dialog2 "Liberate licenses available" \
        "There are some licenses available; great!" info 0 OK
```

---

### General advice

Your logic looks a bit dodgy. Should the complaint about having no licenses be inside that `else` clause?

Also, I'd put the actual `exec` line in its own procedure that does *just that* so that all the places that use it get to have exactly the same version that you can be sure is correct. It keeps the amount of ways in which stuff can go wrong down so that you can hunt any bugs more easily.

Comment: Thanks Donal,

I followed your advice and its working now.
I had a typo and have edited the code now.